# Using Sed To Remove A Line From Text File

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to remove a given line $2 from the file `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` using sed. Here is the command I am running, unfortunately, its not deleting the line. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
 sed -i '/$2/d' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error message?  Do you have write access to the file?

Answer (score 2):

`$2` won't be replaced with its value inside single quotes. Should work with double quotes.

Comment: sed -i "/$2/d" /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Getting an error from sed. `sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unknown command: `3'' Probably because the public key, has special sed characters in it. Is there a way to quote it?

Comment: Use a non-base64 valid character as sed's separator, something like this should work: sed -i "\,$2,d"

Answer (score 1):

Posting a non-sed answer as suggested by Glenn Jackman.  The basic "right answer" was already posted by Tom Zych; note also the comment by holygeek.

```
mv authorized_keys authorized_keys~
fgrep -v "$2" authorized_keys~ >authorized_keys
```

You could probably get by without the temporary file but I'm not at my computer so I'm playing it safe for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the shell

```
while read -r line
do
   case "$line" in 
     *"$2"* ) continue;;
     * ) echo "$line" ;;
   esac
done < /root/.ssh/authorized_keys > tempfile
mv tempfile /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: More like `fgrep -v "$2" authorized_keys` ...!

Comment: To the one who downvote, make sure you know why you downvote.

Comment: @tripleee, you might want to put that comment as an answer. It's the best answer I see here.

Comment: I tried `fgrep -v "$2" /root/.ssh/authorized_keys > /root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and it just clears out the entire authorized_keys file.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot redirect into the file you want to read from, you need a temporary file or some other workaround.